# Add leading zeros to a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

**I have a data column containing phone numbers**

where pandas automatically remove leading zeros from phone numbers upon reading the file.

I couldn't change that behavior, However I tried to add the leading zeros instead.

So I tried this:

```
 # add the missing leading zeros to phone numbers.
 read_file['Phone 1 - Value'] = "0" + read_file['Phone 1 - Value'].astype(str)
 print(read_file.head())
```

But it also didn't work, the strange thing is that when printing the head() it actually works, but when saving the file as a CSV file later on it defaults back to that odd behavior as shown below:

```
read_file.to_csv(export_file_path, index = None, header=True, index_label = True, encoding='utf-8')
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is problem how pandas read numbers.

In file are leading zeros, but pandas convert values to integers, so removed.

For avoid it convert column to strings by `dtype` parameter in `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(export_file_path, dtype={'Phone 1 - Value':str})
```

Comment: I am not reading a CSV file, I am converting from an excel file, while doing this the DataFrame automatically catches the new number format.

Comment: @a7madx7 - So problem is reading csv file by excel? If check csv file by some text editor like Notepad++ I think leading zeros are not removed. But if open csv by excel, it remove them.

Comment: Wow, this is the strangest thing that ever happened to me, It actually was just the excel fault, and BTW the dtype={'Phone 1 - Value':str} also worked for read_excel() function.

Thanks my man.